# Why is my Qt Application freezing if the thread is not a child object of the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

When I change the function which starts a QThread to '_do_print2' in the following 'minimal' example, my MainWindow freezes. For comparision, the upper button will start the QThread without any problems. Why has the thread to be a child object of the MainWindow class?

Im using Python 2.7.6 and Qt 4.8.6.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, time

class MainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton2)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self._do_print)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self._do_print2)
    ## Working function
    def _do_print(self):
        self.thread = Worker(printer)
        self.thread.start() 
    ## Function freezes the MainWindow
    def _do_print2(self):
        thread = Worker(printer)
        thread.start()


def printer():
    while True:
        print "alive"
        time.sleep(1)

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.function = function

    def run(self):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script "freezes" because you told it to do exactly that.

The `Worker` class has a `__del__` method defined, which makes the thread wait (or "freeze" as you put it) until the run method returns. But of course it will never return, because it calls a function which starts a blocking loop that never terminates. The `__del__` method is called because you didn't keep a reference to the thread, and so it gets garbage-collected as soon as the `_do_print2()` method returns (i.e. immediately after the thread starts).

Note that the first thread is not a *child* of the main-window - it's just an instance attribute (which is what keeps it alive). If you remove the `__del__` method, starting the second thread will probably crash the program, because there is then nothing to stop the underlying C++ thread being deleted prematurely.

Comment: So the garbage collector wants to remove the worker thread, is part of the first thread (in which 'window' is running) but has to wait on its removal and therefore blocks its thread. Right?

Comment: @JohnH.K. No, it's the thread's `wait()` that prevents immediate deletion. See the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I did mean the function wait() with 'has to wait'. But this function is in the worker object and not in the mainwindow object. The main thread wants to use the self.__del__ function of the worker - correct?

Comment: @JohnH.K. Yes, `__del__` runs in the main thread, because the `QThread` object is in the main thread.